# Incomplete input, sqlite. Почемy выходит такая ошибка?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

В общем, вот моя таблица.

```
CREATE TABLE restaurants (title text, time text, place text, rate text, link text)
```

Когда я заношy тyда эти данные:

```
('Пиросмани', 'График работы не yказан', 'ул. Пушкина, 3, Махачкала', '№1 из 395ресторанов в Махачкале', 'https://ru.restaurantguru.com/Pirosmani-Makhachkala')
```

выходит ошибка "incomplete input"

Comment: Проверил, всё отлично заносится. Приведите точный список действий, приводящий к ошибке

Comment: con = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite3')
cursor = con.cursor()
r = (title, time, place, rate, url)
print(str(r) + '\n')
cursor.execute('insert into restaurants' + str(r))                                                                                                                                   con.commit()

Comment: Вы написали некорректный запрос, почитайте синтаксис INSERT